# My Drive (Google) is not synced to my new computer

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

I have a new Windows 10 computer and I have installed Backup and Sync from Google but the 55 GB of data I have in My Drive is not downloaded to the new computer.

**Expected Result**
That all the files in the My Drive cloud are downloaded and synced to my new computer after I install and login to Backup and Sync.

**Actual Behavior**

1. If I create a file in the My Drive directory on my local computer, that file is uploaded to Google.
2. If I create a file in the My Drive directory on Google (via Chrome), that file is downloaded to my computer.
3. But the files already present on My Drive when I installed Backup and Sync are never downloaded to my computer.
4. No errors are reported by Backup and Sync.

**Things tested that did not help**

1. I have reinstalled Backup and Sync - multiple times
2. I have disconnected the account - and signed in again to connect it
3. I have cleared the folder AppData/Local/Google

But for some reason Backup and Sync does not pull the old files from the cloud, is it possible that there is something in the Cloud telling my local Backup and Sync not to download the files in My Drive?

Thanks for all any and all tips on how to resolve my issue
Matias

p.s.
*I also posted this at [Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/m2d7d8ppnZc/aJZRarKIBgAJ) but the post became unreadable since all the line breaks were removed.*

***Edit: it seems that it was a problem with Google, the sync started to work properly a few days later when I tried again.***

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

preferences > Google Drive > [x] Sync My drive to this conputer.

Check/enable this option.

Comment: Thank you but I did check that checkbox, it works now even though I have not made any changes. I Guess it was an temporary issue with Google.